# Machine won't boot after upgrade from 18.04.6 to 20.04

Tags: grub2, upgrade, lubuntu, recovery-mode

I just tried to upgrade from Lubuntu 18.04.6 to 20.04 on a Station M2 mini PC. It's like a fancier Raspberry Pi.

The upgrade completed and the computer was functional. Upon reboot, I can't get the machine to load past the initial Firefly logo.

I tried holding down `Shift`, `F2`, `Space`, `ESC` and `F12` to no avail. GRUB won't load and I tried to boot from USB. I'm wondering if something happened to the bootloader.

Comment: Lubuntu 18.04 LTS was the last LXDE release of Lubuntu, and thus *release-upgrades* were not supported beyond 18.04.  Problems were expected which is why it said "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*" in the release notes (eg. https://lubuntu.me/focal-2-released/)   You should re-install.

Comment: What architecture of CPU is there in your Station M2 mini PC? 32-bit PC (i386) or 64-bit PC (amd64) or some arm architecture? A quick glance at some web-site indicates that it has an arm architecture, but it would help if you can confirm that.

Comment: Hi @sudodus. I appreciate you following up over here. It's ARM architecture. RK3566. Below is the wiki I've been working from. So far I've tried to boot from SD card and USB and no dice. Their proprietary firmware tool didn't work on PC either. I haven't tried MaskRom mode yet — I'm a bit intimidated.

https://wiki.t-firefly.com/en/ROC-RK3566-PC/

Comment: I have no arm computer, and cannot help much, but I hope that someone who knows about Lubuntu in arm computers will see your question and help you. - But generally I agree with guiverc, that dist-upgrading from 18.04.x LTS is not likely to succeed. Instead you should try with a fresh installation of 20.04.4 LTS or 22.04.1 LTS. But before that you had better backup everything that you cannot afford to lose. (I hope you can move the drive(s) with valuable data to another computer, where you can back it up.)

Comment: I'll just provide some more info..   Lubuntu hoped to have answers for LXDE upgrades to LXQt releases, even creating documentation on how to *mitigate* some of the problems, however even following those *docs* left QA-testers with troubles (inc. myself) on some installs; yet others were good. In the end it depended on what changes, or additional packages you'd added - thus the decision to *not support* the upgrades. We did not QA test *armhf* or *arm64* but I'd expect your base system to correctly *release-upgrade* and only parts of the GUI be broken (ie. runlevel 1 should be usable)